# Jquery mouseleave & mouseenter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I allow the user to click on the button that says "click me" appears on mouseenter of another button.

Here is the code -

```
<div class="hint"> ?</div>

<div class="desc">
    This is supposed to appear on hover
    This is supposed to appear on hover
    This is supposed to appear on hover
    This is supposed to appear on hover
    <button type="button">
        Click me
    </button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

  var hint = $('.hint');
  var desc = $('.desc');

  hint.mouseenter(function() {
    desc.show();
  });

   hint.mouseleave(function() {
    desc.hide();
  });
});
```

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/20kqjodk/)

Comment: Place `div.desc` inside `div.hint` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Make the `.desc` div a child of your `.hint`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var hint = $('.hint');
  var desc = $('.desc');
  
  hint.mouseenter(function() {
   desc.show();
  });
  
   hint.mouseleave(function() {
   desc.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.hint {
    padding: 20px;
    background: white;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.desc {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 3;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: 20px;
    left: -5px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hint"> ?<div class="desc">
This is supposed to appear on hover
This is supposed to appear on hover
This is supposed to appear on hover
This is supposed to appear on hover
<button type="button">
Click me
</button>
</div></div>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20kqjodk/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Just Place the `.desc` inside the `.hint`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20kqjodk/3/)

For the basic tooltip, you want:

```
<div title="This is my tooltip">
```

For fancier tooltips, [See this](http://www.designer-daily.com/jquery-prototype-mootool-tooltips-12632)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your html with another `div` and add `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event to this.

```js
var con = $('.container');
var desc = $('.desc');

con.mouseenter(function() {
   desc.show();
});

con.mouseleave(function() {
   desc.hide();
});
```

```css
.hint {
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 20px;
  left: -5px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hint"> ?</div>
  <div class="desc">
    This is supposed to appear on hover This is supposed to appear on hover This is supposed to appear on hover This is supposed to appear on hover
    <button type="button">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20kqjodk/9/)**.

If you can't  change the structure of your HTML code try to wait a little before hidding a `desc` div using `setTimeout()` so if the user enter mouse inside this div you will not hide it by clearing the `timeout` check the example bellow :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hide_timeout;
    var hide_after = 100; //100 ms

    var hint = $('.hint');
    var desc = $('.desc');

    hint.mouseenter(function() {
      desc.show();
    });

     hint.mouseleave(function() {
       hide_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
          desc.hide();
       },hide_after);

    });

     desc.mouseenter(function() {
      clearTimeout(hide_timeout);
    });

    desc.mouseleave(function() {
      desc.hide();      
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var hide_timeout;
        var hide_after = 100; //100 ms

        var hint = $('.hint');
        var desc = $('.desc');

        hint.mouseenter(function() {
          desc.show();
        });

         hint.mouseleave(function() {
           hide_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
              desc.hide();
           },hide_after);

        });

         desc.mouseenter(function() {
          clearTimeout(hide_timeout);
        });

        desc.mouseleave(function() {
          desc.hide();   
        });
    });
```

```css
.hint {
padding: 20px;
background: white;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
}


.desc {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 3;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: 20px;
    left: -5px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hint"> ?</div>

<div class="desc">
This is supposed to appear on hover
This is supposed to appear on hover
This is supposed to appear on hover
This is supposed to appear on hover
<button type="button">
Click me
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1 - You can add the `show()` and `hide()` when the tooltip is hover : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20kqjodk/1/)

2 - You can use only css to show or hide it. Not sure you need JS for simple things like that.

Answer (score 0):

This [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/20kqjodk/5/) shows what I think you want to achieve. The trick is to also catch the event that is triggerd, when the mouse enters a other element.

```
$('*').not('.hint').not('.desc').not('.desc>button').mouseenter(function() {
   desc.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $('.desc').hide();

 $(document).on('mouseenter','.hint',function(){
  $('.desc').show();
 })

});
```